# Number of distributive lattices with exactly one atom and four irreducible elements in total

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, set-theory, order-theory

I was given the following problem:

> How many distributive lattices are there with exactly one atom and four irreducible elements in total?

An irreducible element, in this context, is an $x$ in the lattice set $L$ such that $x = y \lor z \to x =y $ or $x = z$ for any $y, z \in L$, where $\lor$ is the supremum operator.

There clearly are distributive lattices satisfying this property. Take, for example, the Hasse diagram of $P(\{a, b, c\}, \subseteq)$ with its typical cube form. Add to this diagram a minimum node $0$, such that it looks like this:

[image]

Here, $I_1, ... I_3$ are irreducible elements, and so is the atom $a$, and the graph is a distributive lattice. In fact, my intuition is that one can "extend" elementary distributive lattices satisfying the constraint$-$such as the one whose Hasse diagram is above$-$ indefinitely while preserving the number of irreducible elements and the unique atom. For example,

[image]

is still distributive and satisfies the constraints. All I did was "add a floor" to the cube, and I could repeat that step indefinitely.

So far my intuition goes. But I am unable to prove this at all. I was requested to give a formal proof or justification of whatever answer I give, and here's where I'm falling short. How could one tackle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can find exactly 5 such distributive lattices, the ones depicted on the Hasse diagrams below. The atom is highlighted in blue, the other irreducibles in red. Textual descriptions are provided below.

[image: Hasse diagrams of distributive lattices with one atom and four irreducibles]

Our proof uses the following well-known result:

> **Theorem.** (Birkhoff) Every finite distributive lattice $H$ arises as the the lattice of lower sets of the poset of irreducible elements of $H$.

Since the distributive lattices of interest have exactly 4 irreducibles, one could feasibly start by enumerating all 16 posets on 4 elements and proceed from there. But we know the one-atom restriction, which means we can start by fixing one element as that atom $0$: all other elements $x$ must satisfy $0 \leq x$, so it suffices to enumerate the posets with 3 elements. You can make quick work of these by drawing Hasse diagrams, or by considering maximal chains. Either way, you'll find five such posets:

- $P_1$: $1;\: 2;\: 3$
- $P_2$: $1 \leq 2;\: 3$
- $P_3$: $1 \leq 2;\: 1 \leq 3$
- $P_4$: $1 \leq 3;\: 2 \leq 3$
- $P_5$: $1 \leq 2 \leq 3$

This means that there are 5 distributive lattices with exactly one atom and four irreducibles. While you don't have to actually construct them to answer the question as stated, I'll describe which ones they are:

- $P_1$ gives rise to your example above, the 8-element Boolean algebra with a bottom element adjoined (so 9 elements in total).
- $P_2$ gives rise to the product of the 2-element Boolean algebra and the 3-chain, with a bottom element adjoined (so 7 elements in total).
- $P_3$ gives rise to the 4-element Boolean algebra with a bottom element adjoined twice (so 6 elements in total).
- $P_4$ gives rise to the 4-element Boolean algebra with a bottom and top element adjoined (so 6 elements in total).
- $P_5$ gives rise to the 5-chain.

And that's all of them!

Your strategy had a few problems:

- Your definition of irreducible does not quite correspond to the usual one: the bottom element has to be excluded (since one could regard it as the join of no elements).
- You drew the Hasse diagram of the 8-element Boolean algebra incorrectly (compare with mine above, you have an extra edge).
- Finally, the 12-element poset you constructed never satisfied the definition of distributive lattice (what would be the least upper bound of $I_1$, $I_2$ and $I_3$?). This led you down the wrong path, where you tried to argue that we can find infinitely many such lattices.

*edit:* *an [upscaled version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7Fbx.png) of the diagrams is now available.*

Comment: Honestly, I had a hard time to understand the difference between $P_2$ and $P_3$. Eventually I understood when I started to depict the posets on my own. This is because I often write $a\leq b, c$ as a short for $a \leq b$ and $a \leq c$. But in the end I agree with all your conclusions (+1)

Comment: @amrsa: Following your suggestion, I changed the separator from comma to semicolon in the offending section, to make it clearer that these mean to denote separate chains. I also added the Hasse diagrams of the distributive lattices in question.

Comment: Yes, that is more clear, thanks!

Comment: A very clear answer, thank you so much!